# Connecting to marketplace data using the SnowSQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

To connect marketplace data we have a UI process by creating an object we can able to see the data in snowflake account. I have couple of confusions on this:

1. Is marketplace data stores in consumers account OR Is it virtual data access from marketplace provider.
2. To access marketplace data without using API, how we can automate the process using SnowSQL. Tried with different approaches did not get the luck.

Can someone please help me on these confusions.

Comment: Marketplace data is stored in the Provider account and is accessed in the Consumer account via a database created in that Consumer account. Please update your question to explain what SQL statement(s) you are trying to run via SnowSQL and what issues you are facing when running them?